# How to prepopulate target in Primefaces picklist?

Tags: primefaces, picklist

How to prepopulate target in Primefaces picklist?

I initialized `DualListModel` with following code:

```
List<Dimension> dimensionsSource = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
List<Dimension> dimensionsTarget = new ArrayList<Dimension>();

Dimension dimension = new Dimension("Year", "year", "name");
dimensionsSource.add(dimension);

dimension = new Dimension("Quarter", "quarter", "id");
dimensionsSource.add(dimension);

dimension = new Dimension("Month", "month", "id");
dimensionsTarget.add(dimension);

dimensions = new DualListModel<Dimension>(dimensionsSource, dimensionsTarget);
```

When `PickList` is appears on screen it has "Month" in target list, but when I submit data `getTarget()` returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem! The reason was in wrong converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "dimensionsConverter")
public class DimensionsConverter implements Converter {
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s)     {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    DualListModel<Dimension> value = (DualListModel<Dimension>)((PickList) uiComponent).getValue();
    List<Dimension> source = value.getSource();
    for (Dimension dimension : source) {
        if(s.equals(dimension.getTableAndOrderColumn())){
            return dimension;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
    return ((Dimension)o).getTableAndOrderColumn();
}
```

Converter is trying to find a "Month" in source list while month was in target list :) 
Thanx to all for your time!